# Braintree - Why braintree transactions created via API, or via sandbox, take so much time before settled?

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, payment-processing, braintree

Whenever, I create a transaction via Braintree API, or via their sandbox, it goes through many statuses like Authorized, Submitted for Settlement, Settled ... and all this takes 24 hours approximately. I want to ask is there a way by which I can create a transaction in sandbox/api and it is settled or disputed instantly. I don't know why it takes so much time ... e.g. in online shopping my credit card is charged immediately. How can same be achieved via braintree payments sandbox ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<sub>I work at Braintree. It looks like we already responded to your [support email](https://support.braintreepayments.com/), but I'll post this here for others who have the same problem.</sub>

Each client library has a method to instantly settle a transaction in Sandbox. For [PHP, it's in the TestHelper](https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/blob/master/tests/TestHelper.php#L112-L117):

```
class Braintree_TestHelper
{
    . . .

    public static function settle($transactionId)
        {
            $http = new Braintree_Http(Braintree_Configuration::$global);
            $path = Braintree_Configuration::$global->merchantPath() . '/transactions/' . $transactionId . '/settle';
            $http->put($path);
        }

    . . .
}
```

In production, any transaction that you run will generally show up as a charge on a credit card instantly, but it isn't "permanent" and the money won't actually move until the transaction has settled. In other words, even though settlement can take 24 hours, the charge doesn't take that long to show up on the card.

Comment: I followed this approach of settling a transaction. It settled the transaction on sandbox, but it didn't invoke the "Transaction disbursed" webhook i set on the sandbox. Any reason for that? The webhook is called properly when transaction settles without the api call.

Comment: The disbursement happens on a set schedule even when you manually trigger settlement. You should receive the webhook sometime after 04:15 UTC.

Comment: @agf can you explain a bit more? I'm using Braintree with composer (autoload and stuff) and `Braintree_TestHelper::settle('someid');` does not work, should I include the class separately. Also, this `settle` method can be used anywhere? Transaction id must be a valid transaction object? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, by "does not work" I meant `Fatal error: Class 'Braintree_TestHelper' not found`

Comment: @viarnes Yes, you have to require the test helper separately.

Comment: @viarnes If you're using the composer braintree classes do this:
`\Braintree\Test\Transaction::settle('someid');`

Answer (score 1):

Things have slightly changed since the answer. The idea is the same, but as of the 2023 version of the PHP SDK, this is a possible way to "force-settle" a transaction:

```php
use Braintree\Configuration;

Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Configuration::merchantId('yourmid');
Configuration::publicKey('yourpbk');
Configuration::privateKey('yourprk');
Configuration::gateway()->testing()->settle('transactionid');
```